# Android C# HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: android, html-agility-pack

How do I use HtmlAgilityPack with Android (Mono for Android - C#)? I've added the reference, but I keep getting this error:

> Error CS0012: The type 'System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable' is defined
>   in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0

Comment: Have you ever solved this ? I'm having the exactly same error. I even downloaded the samples from Xamarin's GitHub and used the compiled AgilityPack they have provided there but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

I have incorporated HtmlAglilityPack into the base library assembly I use in all of my MonoDroid projects with great success. I have not even tried to use them in precompiled form, but simply added it's source to my project.

I then shamelessly edited HtmlWeb.cs to throw out the Windows stuff:

lines 893 to 903 (may have somewhat changed, just look around near there):

```
        if (!helper.GetIsDnsAvailable())
        {
        #if Android
            contentType = def;
        #else
            //do something.... not at full trust
            try
            {
                RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot;
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey(extension, false);
                if (reg != null) contentType = (string)reg.GetValue("", def);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                contentType = def;
            }
        #endif
        }
```

lines 934 to 946 (may have somewhat changed, just look around near there):

```
        if (helper.GetIsRegistryAvailable())
        {
        #if Android
            ext = def;
        #else
            try
            {
                RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot;
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type\" + contentType, false);
                if (reg != null) ext = (string)reg.GetValue("Extension", def);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ext = def;
            }
        #endif
        }
```

I then added `Android` to the conditional compilation symbols of my project.

My references are:

```
Microsoft.CSharp
Mono.Android
System
System.Core
System.Data
System.Xml
System.Xml.Linq
```

Please add a comment, telling if you can compile it now, or if you need more information.